# linking javascript file to wordpress child theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to link a javascript file to my child theme.  I've looked at the WordPress Codex and numerous examples, but it still is not working.  I'm working on localhost, so from what I have read, i want to use the get_stylesheet_directory().  I've echoed it out and it is pointing to the correct path.  Below is my code that is placed in my functions.php child theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );
function theme_js() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/theme.js',    array('jquery'), '', true );
}
```

My javascript file looks like this:

```
/**
 * Custom Theme Styles
 */
( function( $ ) {

$('.main-navigation li a').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(link).offset().top
    }, 1500);
});
 })( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The src string in the enqueue needs to be a URL, not a path, so you need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_stylesheet_directory()`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );
function theme_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js',    array('jquery'), '', true );
}
```

Comment: Lol, actually, I think this is the correct answer, not mine! So let's answer this question while we're at it, do you have to register a script first before you enqueue it? Are we both right? I agree a script would have to be loaded with a URL, not an internal path. So I don't have to minus my own answer I'll delete it in a day or so....

Comment: No, you do not have to register first. In general, you only need to register if you are going to register in one part of your code and enqueue somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for both of your help.  I implemented both of them and now it is working!

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the script first, then enqueue it. Here is the codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script